# How do I rebuild my XCode4 project if only one resource file (.PNG) has changed?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

If I update a .PNG file (using an external editor like Photoshop), how can I quickly rebuild my XCode4 project without doing a full Clean/Rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Build without going through a clean and rebuild cycle.

If you are worried that you are changing the file outside of Xcode and want to mark it as changed just run `touch` on it from the command line.